# Display stdout and stderr of subprocess seamlessly

Tags: python, subprocess

There are a few other questions around dealing on how to print `stdout` and `stderr` of a subprocess. The final objective would be to run a command with the same output it would have on `bash`.

I'm currently with something like this:

```
with subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', 'myJar.jar'],
        env=dict(os.environ, JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx64M"),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line.decode('utf-8'), end='')
```

What I'm missing is the `stderr` part. I'd like to avoid redirecting it with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and instead keep it as it would be on the shell.
Another caveat is that the command I'm using has colorized output by default and ideally I'd like to maintain it.

How can I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I get You right but You are missing `stdout` part right?
Try this example and change the command as needed:

```
def create_dir(self, path: str):
    cmd = 'sudo mkdir {}'.format(path)
    _sw = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = _sw.communicate()
    return out, err
```

`shell` option depends on needs, as I remember out will be in `b'String'` format

Comment: I wrongly wrote `stdout` after the code block; what I meant is that I'm currently printing that correctly but `stderr` is not accounted for yet.

Comment: Did You try the example? Running above on Win10: `(b'', b"'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n")`

Comment: This wait for the subprocess to terminate, doesn't it? Is there any way to get any output as it is written to PIPE?

Comment: Yes it does wait. Try this: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python

Comment: this works better, however I can't figure out how to integrate `stderr` in that loop.